# Very modest contract: leading with a king makes good sense (5)

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

This is from a Times puzzle in an old book:

> (DOWN) 4. Very modest contract: leading with a king makes good sense (5)

I know the answer is LOGIC but I can't see why - please can somebody explain it?

Comment: Out of interest, do you know how old the book is? I doubt the first reference in @hexomino's explanation (which I'm sure is correct) would be used nowadays, and probably not the second either

Comment: I found the crossword: it's no. 22810 from 2004 - more recent than I'd have guessed

Answer (score 6):

It's a tricky one but I think the idea is as follows

> [**LOG**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Frogs_Who_Desired_a_King) is the king who "leads" (begins the word) and the "very modest contract" is **IC** which, I think, refers to a contract in [bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_bridge) where a single club is the lowest contract as far as I understand (although I don't really know the rules). Also, as mentioned by Darrel Hoffman in the comments, "good sense" is the definition.

Comment: Wow, I thought for sure the king would be Og the Biblical character.

Comment: And obviously rot13(tbbq frafr vf ybtvp)...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Oh yeah, I thought that bit was a given. Do you reckon I add it in for completeness?

Comment: Might as well?  I don't know what the rules are for how complete an answer needs to be...